# Critical points of an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone help me in this exercise?

> Be $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
> $$f(x, y) = \int_x^y \dfrac{t-1}{1+t^6}\ \text{d}t$$
> Determine the critical point(s) of $f$ and classify it/them.

> Be then $A = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: |x| \leq 1, |y| \leq 1\}$. Determine $f(A)$

I tried to solve the integral but there is no simple way to do it, I think. I tried to see the denominator as a sum of cubes

$$t^6+1 = (t^2)^3 + 1^3 = ((t^2+1)(t^4-t^2+1)$$ but it did not lead me to a suitable solution. Partial fractions seem no the case either. How could I do it?

Also the second request: can someone explain what does it mean $f(A)$? I really cannot understand how to proceed for this. How can I write the "function of a set"?

**EDIT**

My first question was really silly. Thanks to the two people who commented, I really remembered the differentiating under the integral sign theorem!

Yet I need some help for the second point...

Comment: First: You should have learned in single-variable calculus that you can differentiate integrals like this without actually first doing the anti-differentiation. What is the relevant theorem? Second, $f(A)$ denotes the set of *values* of $f$ at all the points of $A$.

Comment: If $F'(t) = \frac{t-1}{1+t^6}$, then $f(x,y)  = F(y) - F(x)$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -F'(x) $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = F'(y)$. Note that you don't need $F$; you only need to know $F'$.

Comment: @CatalinZara Yes! Thanks to Ted who remembered me that, I was going to write down what you wrote. At least you confirmed it. It was a really silly question... Thank you for this point!

Comment: No, not differentiating under the integral sign. That's something different. :) However, if you actually want to find $f(-1,1) = -f(1,-1)$, you're going to need to do the integral. So partial fractions it is. Remember that you will have to factor $t^4-t^2+1$ as a product of quadratics. Or perhaps they want a qualitative description of $f(A)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, it's from a past exam and it says "Determine $f(A)$ being careful to justify and motivate the answer"